# Detect Views that don't exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a new ASP.NET MVC 2 Website which is going to replace an old php site.
I want to make sure that if any old favourites are used it will show a 404 not found message. I have trapped 404 in the Web.config which works when an incorrect url is used e.g. (/Sales/MyView). 
But it returns an application error for the following example (/Sales), i.e. when only a controller name is used without an action.

Is there a way to trigger a 404 error in this senario to avoid any application errors.

Cheers,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

In your global.asax, you can specify the default MapRoute for the Sales controller as your 404 page.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. However "Sales" was just an example and it doesn't actually exist. What I'm trying to do is force anything that doesn't exist to a default "page not found" view. So far I can only do this if the url is in the format {controller}/{action}. I'm trying to cover all bases and trap all errors with a nice error page. If the url is in the format {controller} (with no action) I can trap the error but not with a 404 it just goes into the default error page.